# forwarding large files on servers

Tags: python, web-applications, flask

I have two Flask servers A and B. My user is on machine C. A is the public interface machine. The user wants to retrieve a 500GB octet-stream from B, but only the public interface on A is exposed.

So I'd like something where:

User on machine C sends GET request to server A, request gets routed to server B, server B replies to C with the 500GB octet-stream without going through A.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

What would be the problem exactly?

Personally I would recommend setting up an Nginx server at both ends to serve the file from the filesystem. Using Flask for hosting files is a waste of resources.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial showing how this is done? I'm quite new to this.

Comment: It would depend a bit on the operating system you are using and everything. But here's a basic guide for installing on Ubuntu 12.04: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin

Comment: After install you can continue with setting up vhosts: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3

Comment: If I understand nginx properly, it only serves as a proxy and must be running on some server, which then forwards the request/replies to other servers? So no matter what the large file would need to be sent through the server running nginx?

Comment: It can serve as a proxy server but it can do much more than that. You can instruct nginx to serve local files by using the `root` parameter. Here are a few examples: http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2010/07/nginx-primer/